# Regarding number of epochs for torchvision models

Tags: pytorch, pre-trained-model, torchvision

I was trying to find, how many epochs was the pretrained Alexnet model (available from torchvision) trained for on Imagenet and also what learning rate was used? I tried checking the checkpoint keys to see if any epoch info was stored.
Any suggestions on how to find it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/615#issuecomment-462333770) on GitHub by a PyTorch team member, most of the training was done with a variant of https://github.com/pytorch/examples/tree/master/imagenet. All the models were trained on Imagenet. According to the file:

- The default learning rate schedule starts at 0.1 and decays by a factor of 10 every 30 epochs, though they recommend using 0.01 for Alexnet as initial learning rate.
- The default value for epochs is 90.